# Changing Background of GridMvc Column on Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcgrid

I am using Grid MVC in asp.net mvc project . I get requirement where i need to change the background color of row if there is certain condition e.g. column name "Response" equals to "ERROR" then i need to change row color to red

### **Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Grid.Models.Client>
@using GridMvc.Html

@{
Layout = null;
 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>    

<title>Index</title>
 </head>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Client"))
{
 <body style="margin:30px">

<br />
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4> Search Criteria:</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                 <p>Reference :</p>
                 <input type="text" name="ref" style="width:120px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <p>Date :</p>
                 <input type="date" name="date" style="width:150px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <p>Time :</p>
                 <input type="time" name="time" style="width:120px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" style="width:60px" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<br />

<div style="width:800px;">        
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
                {                        
                    columns.Add(c => c.Type).Titled("Type").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(c => c.Description).Titled("Description");
                    columns.Add(c => c.DateTime).Titled("DateTime");
                    columns.Add(c => c.Reference).Titled("Reference");
                    columns.Add(c => c.Response).Titled("Response");
                }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
</div>
```

}

### **_Grid.cshtml**

```
@using GridMvc.Columns
@model GridMvc.IGrid
@if (Model == null){ return; }
@{
var gridClinetId = "grid-mvc-" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : Model.Id);
}
<div id="@gridClinetId" class="grid-outer @(Model.EnablePaging ? "paged" : string.Empty)">
@* Draw grid top items infomation panel *@
<div class="grid-wrap">
    <table class="table table-striped grid-table" data-lang="@Model.Language">
        @* Draw grid header *@
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(column.HeaderRenderer.Render(column, column.Title))
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.ItemsCount == 0)
            {
                <tr class="grid-empty-text">
                    <td colspan="@Model.Columns.Count()">
                        @Model.EmptyGridText
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (object item in Model.ItemsToDisplay)
                {
                <tr class="grid-row @Model.GetRowCssClasses(item)">
                    @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(column.CellRenderer.Render(column, column.GetCell(item).ToString()))
                    }
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @if (Model.EnablePaging && Model.Pager != null && Model.Pager.PageCount > 1)
    {
        <div class="grid-footer">
            <div class="grid-footer-info">
                Displaying items @(((Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * Model.Pager.PageSize) + 1)
                - @(((Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * Model.Pager.PageSize) + Model.DisplayingItemsCount)
                (@Model.ItemsCount)
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("_GridPager", Model.Pager)
        </div>
    }
@* Draw pager *@
</div>
</div>
@* Init Grid.Mvc client script *@
<script>
if (typeof (jQuery) != 'undefined' && typeof (jQuery.fn.gridmvc) != 'undefined') {
    var grid = $("#@gridClinetId").gridmvc();
    window.gridMvcControl = grid;//when using only 1 grid on the page
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id))
    {
     <text>if (typeof (window.pageGrids) == 'undefined') window.pageGrids = {};  window.pageGrids['@Model.Id'] = grid;</text>
    }
}
</script>
```

### **_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
$('.grid-table tr td:nth-child(4)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('ERROR') != -1;
}).closest('tr').css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Comment: i tried the above function inside _Grid.cshtml but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you put it in a jQuery ready event? `jQuery(function() { //code here });`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.grid-table tr td:nth-child(4)').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().indexOf('ERROR') != -1;
        }).closest('tr').css("backgroundColor", "red");
    });

</script>

Comment: i placed the above script code inside the page _Grid.cshtml

Comment: i got the issue i think there is logical error in .text().indexOf('ERROR') != -1;

Comment: i tried using .text() == 'ERROR'; but it does not work.

Comment: Try breaking into parts and then debug with the console

Comment: Solved. actually Grid was bind to List which has Id column as well which was not added in Grid but existed in actual list so it was checking the list instead of grid and when i made child(5) it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in server size method for this. [SetRowCssClasses()](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GridMvc/GridMvc/GridBase.cs).

In Index.cshtml, use below

```
@Html.Grid(Model).SetRowCssClasses(
    item => item.Response=="ERROR"? "cssClassRed" : string.Empty)
      .Columns(columns =>
    {
```

"cssClassRed" is injected to rows that satisfied the condition.

```
<tr class="grid-row cssClassRed">
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, just add the column you want conditional color:

```
columns.Add(p => p.DifferenceQty).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(p => RenderCustomCSS(p.LogicQty, p.RealQty)).Titled("Cantidad total").SetWidth(70).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
```

and create a helper to set the custom render value (in the same view)

```
@helper RenderCustomCSS(double Value, double ValueCompared)
{
    <p class="@(Value !=ValueCompared ? "gridDangerCell" : "")">@Value</p>
}
```

in the css:

```
.gridDangerCell
{
    color: red;
}
```